# ASP.NET 5 Routing Navigation with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET 5 with AngularJS. I've 2 actions with views in MVC (Home and Web). I've 4 client routing with Angular. All of these 4 client routing happens in first view (Home). In the first view, I want an anchor link to the second action in MVC (Web). In MVC, I'm using attribute routing. I can't navigate to the 2nd action from the view 1 Home, because it uses Angular Routing and if I put an ActionLink to 2nd action it redirects me to the 1st action with first view in Angular. My code is given below

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("{*url}")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("Home/Web")]
    public IActionResult Web()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Angular File:

```
app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'static/home.html'
    })
    .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'static/about.html'
    })
    .state('contact', {
        url: '/contact',
        templateUrl: 'static/contact.html'
    })
    .state('tutorial', {
        url: '/tutorial',
        templateUrl: 'static/tutorial.html'
    })

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

Here is my Startup class with default routes in MVC:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes => 
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Here is my _Layout.cshtml

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="/about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/tutorial">Tutorials</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Web", "Web", "Home")
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

There is no server configuration file such as web.config. I'm using instead attribute routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the mvc controllers from angular in the following way:

In your angular file use the template URL for referencing the mvc controller:

```
app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider",      function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    templateUrl: 'home/Home'
})
.state('about', {
    templateUrl: 'home/About'
})
.state('contact', {
    templateUrl: 'home/Contact'
})
.state('tutorial', {
    templateUrl: 'home/Tutorial'
})

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

And return the views as partial views in the mvc controller adding the functionality that you want

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("{*url}")]
    public IActionResult Home()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("Home/About")]
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("Home/Contact")]
    public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("Home/Tutorial")]
    public IActionResult Tutorial()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Will it work as fast as my current Angular view if I use MVC partial View?

Comment: I'm not really sure but I don't see any difference when I use it. The best part is that you get to use the mvc controllers before rendering the view so that you could control the view with angular and with .net

Comment: If you want to dynamically set the routes it's better to use ngnewrouter and it should work too by referencing to the mvc controller:  function Controller($router) {
  $router.config([
    { path: '/', redirectTo: '/home' },
    { path: '/home', component: 'home/Home' },
    { path: '/about', component: 'home/About' }
  ]);
}

Comment: Ive never used ir though so I'll apreciate if you tell us if it works

Comment: Ok let me try, I'll get back to you soon.

Comment: Actually I'm confronting some issues while using Angular new Router with ASP.NET 5. Still trying to resolve it but it takes time. So I decided to not to use SPA framework of Angular because of this URL Routing issue. I'm using your way of routing as you mentioned above. Hope so I'm right to do so.