# How to stop MVC routing and allow only angular routing in MVC5 application?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a MVC5 application.
I have to apply Angular routing to it and am able to apply that.
But on any postback the application goes back to the MVC routing again.
Please suggest how to stop MVC routing when we intend to use angular routing in a MVC application?

For ex : I have a set of scaffold pages for a table to perform CRUD operations.
To apply Angular routing it seems the Layout of the views to be made null.
So on a save button click in Create or Edit, the data gets saved but because of its postback, the routing changes from angular to mvc and the page gets displayed with out a layout which means it is going to mvc routing.
Please suggest.

Comment: I am new to work on a combination of mvc and angular js, pls suggest dont negative vote...

Answer (score 0):

You should take the crud functionality to an API rest with the methods post put get etc.

Then you have o define an index.cshtml and set there your angular structure with ngapp and ngview. In this file you should include those elements that are constant in your app (i.e. menu, footer)

Once you have that, create the config of the route provider and set there your routes. In the templateUrl field redirect to a method of an MVC controller.

Finally in the method of the MVC controller return the view that you want for that state.

If you want, for example, the view of a table with all the content you have in a table of your db, you should use the Angular controller and send an ajax request to the API we did (get) then you save the response in $scope.data and in the view you can draw your table with ng-repeat and $scope.data.

It requires you to change the basic architecture of your application but it provides great routing.

Comment: Check out my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657436/asp-net-5-routing-navigation-with-angularjs/33658647#33658647 for understanding how to implement the routing